# CREATE TABLE reverse engineering in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle SQL Developer, there's a "SQL" tab for each table. This tab contains most of the SQL code (`CREATE TABLE`, `CREATE TRIGGER`, etc) that's needed to recreate the table.

Is this information available programatically from the database system, or is this an application feature of SQL Developer?  If the former, what commands/statements would I need to run to retrieve this information?  If the later, are there any clever ways to get SQL Developer to export these statements?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using Oracle 9i+ then you are looking for the DBMS_METADATA package. http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96612/d_metada.htm.  It will allow you to extract whatever DDL you want.

If you are looking for more specific information there is a whole host of views you can access for specific data elements similar to the ones given by @Quassnoi.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of information, but here are the main queries:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    dba_tables

SELECT  *
FROM    dba_tab_columns

SELECT  *
FROM    dba_ind_columns
```

To see what `SQL Developer` actually outputs, enable trace for all sessions with a `LOGON TRIGGER` and look into the trace file created by `SQL Developer`'s internal session.

Comment: +1 for useful information, but there's already something in SQL Developer that's pulling all of this together into the needed CREATE TABLE statements.  I want access to that.

Comment: @Alan: there is `DBMS_METADATA.get_ddl`, but `AFAIR` it doesn't output triggers, permissions etc. Don't know exactly how `SQL Developer` behaves, but `Allround Automations PL/SQL Developer` does not rely on `DBMS_METADATA.get_ddl`, it queries the `DBA_*` views and builds `DDL` internally.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `DDL`  of your database objects.

You can use the Oracle bundled `DBMS_METADATA` package to get it, from any PL/SQL prompt, with the `GET_DDL` function.

Answer (score 0):

I use TOAD vs Oracle SQL Developer.

When I click on a "Script" tab when viewing an object (like a table) TOAD executes a whole host of queries and then compiles the "script" from the output of all of these queries.

dba_tables
dba_tab_columns
dba_ind_columns

...

I think replicating this functionality would be a tedious task.

Comment: Yes, it would  be tedious, which is why I was hoping there was programmatic access to said functionality.